# Looped menu repeats itself

Tags: c++, loops, menu, categories

I'm having trouble with having the menu repeating itself after it choosing the wrong option. My directions are to read from an external file and use it in the menu. I need to read bank statements, put them into categories, and then add them up. I'm not too sure on how to add up the bank statements, and I also can't get it to read out anything once you choose the number.

Here are the bank statements:

```
20-Sep-13   c   Restaurant  MCDONALD'S M429 MURFREESBORO TN     $5.03
20-Sep-13   c   Groceries   KROGER #564 MURFREESBORO TN     $5.00
18-Sep-13   c   Restaurant  THE OLIVE GARD0 MURFREESBORO TN     $42.98
17-Sep-13   c   Mortgage    Bank of America MORTGAGE        $1049.00
17-Sep-13   c   Groceries   KROGER MURFREESBORO TN              $37.60
17-Sep-13   c   Restaurant  SUBWAY 0 MURFREESBORO TN        $24.04
17-Sep-13   c   Groceries   KROGER #564 MURFREESBORO TN         $5.00
16-Sep-13   c   Groceries   DOLLAR-GENERAL WOODBURY TN          $98.31
16-Sep-13   c   Gas         RUTHERFORD COOP WOODBURY TN         $59.80
16-Sep-13   c   Restaurant  D AND J PIZZA A WOODBURY TN         $12.09
13-Sep-13   c   Restaurant  PANERA BREAD #9 MURFREESBORO TN     $30.40
13-Sep-13   c   Groceries   KROGER #564 MURFREESBORO TN         $3.88
9-Sep-13    c   Groceries   KROGER MURFREESBORO TN              $58.62
6-Sep-13    c   Entertainment   DIRECTV ONLINE PMT ***          $150.00
6-Sep-13    c   Gas         Thornton # 605 MURFREESBORO TN      $58.00
4-Sep-13    c   Entertainment   REDBOX MURFREESBORO TN          $1.27
4-Sep-13    c   Groceries   WAL-MART #5057 MURFREESBORO TN      $27.36
4-Sep-13    c   Restaurant  SUBWAY 0 WOODBURY TN                $7.88
3-Sep-13    c   Groceries   KROGER MURFREESBORO TN              $75.04
3-Sep-13    c   Groceries   WAL Wal-Mart Su MURFREESBORO TN     $31.43
3-Sep-13    c   Restaurant  SUBWAY 0 WOODBURY TN                $30.72
3-Sep-13    c   Groceries   DOLLAR-GENERAL WOODBURY TN          $5.38
3-Sep-13    c   Groceries   KROGER MURFREESBORO TN              $4.72
29-Aug-13   c   Gas         RUTHERFORD COOP WOODBURY TN         $15.05
29-Aug-13   c   Restaurant  HARDEE'S 150184 WOODBURY TN         $5.21
27-Aug-13   c   Gas         THORTONS #612 MURFREESBORO TN       $53.00
27-Aug-13   c   Groceries   KROGER MURFREESBORO TN              $44.37
26-Aug-13   c   Groceries   KROGER MURFREESBORO TN              $34.24
26-Aug-13   c   Restaurant  CRACKER BARREL SMYRNA TN            $12.84
26-Aug-13   c   Groceries   KROGER MURFREESBORO TN              $10.00
```

This is my code so far:

```
//Emily Kounlavong
//CSC 1170-003 BUCHER
//OLA7
//November 11
/*This program will create a menu for the user and display the amount of money spent in        each category
depending on the number the user picks. It will display the menu over and over until the      user quits.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main ()

{
    //DECLARE VARIABLES
    float categoryRestaurants;
    float categoryGroceries;
    float categoryMortage;
    float categoryGas;
    float categoryEntertainment;
    string spent;
    string amountOne;
    float amountTwo;
    float amountThree;
    float amountFour;
    float amountFive;
    int choice = 0;
    string category;
    string categoryQuit;
    string fileName;
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;

    //OPEN THE FILE
    inData.open("ola6FinancialData.txt");

    //INTERACT
    cout << "HELLO THERE :D" << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "Enter the menu number for the category you are interested in" << endl;
    cout << "And the program will show you how much was spent in that category." << endl;

    //MENU OPTIONS
    do
    {
        cout << "**********************************************" << endl;
        cout << "1. Restaurants" << endl;
        cout << "2. Groceries" << endl;
        cout << "3. Mortage" << endl;
        cout << "4. Gas" << endl;
        cout << "5. Entertainment" << endl;
        cout << "6. Quit the program" << endl;
        cout << "**********************************************" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }   
    while ((choice > 0) && (choice < 6));

    //FILE STUFF    
    switch (choice) 
    {


        case 1: 
            cout << "The total spent for Restaurants is " << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "The total spent for Groceries is " << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "The total spent for Mortage is " << endl;
            break;

        case 4: 
            cout << "The total spent for Gas is " << endl;
            break;

        case 5: 
            cout << "The total spent for Entertainment is " << endl;
            break;

        case 6:
            cout << "Thanks for using my program. Have a great day! Goodbye." << endl;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "That was not a correct choice. Please try again." << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is horribly long. Trying shortening it to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), *please*.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have the condition of you `do-while` mixed up.

```
while ((choice > 0) && (choice < 6));
```

This will loop as long as `choice` is greater than zero and less than six. First of all, the second condition is wrong (according to your user interface, six should be an acceptable option). Even then, this is probably the reverse of what you want - I believe you'd like the options menu to loop on incorrect choices, not the correct ones! So try this:

```
while ((choice < 0) || (choice > 6));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so fast!

Comment: Should the semicolon be at the end of the statement?

Comment: Yes, it's a `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question **asks how to do a while loop**:

```
int choice;

cout << "Enter a choice: " << endl;
cin >> choice;

while (choice != 0) {
    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            cout << "You entered: " << choice << endl;
            break;
        //all your other options go here..
        default: {
            cout << "Default option goes here..." << endl;
        }
    }
            //this is the important part: you have to update the menu option
            //by prompting the user for a new value:
    cout << "Enter a choice: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
}
```

NOTE:

**This is a naive example: there is no error checking or input validation.** However, that is something you can do on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying so fast!